# Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate

I am working on a requirement which required Digital Signature on PDF files in ASP.Net C# and developed one application who gets the client certificate using USB token on my local machine. But, When hosting this application on IIS server getting error **'Current Session is not Interactive'**.

Anyone have any idea, how can we get X509Certificates from client machine in ASP.Net C# and this application hosted on IIS server not console application.

My code for reference:

```
private void getSign()
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    X509Certificate2 cert = null;
    //manually chose the certificate in the store
    X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates, null, null, X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
    if (sel.Count > 0)
        cert = sel[0];
    else
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Certificate not found");
        return;
    }
    SignWithThisCert(cert);
}
```

Comment: `get X509Certificates from client machine` -- why you need that? If you need to use client certificates to sign PDF, then this operation MUST be executed on a client, not server.

Comment: @Crypt32 I have a web application which is hosted on IIS. In this user upload PDF and digitally signed by his/her personal USB token. All this activity perform on web application. We have required X509Certificates for digital signing of PDF which is stored in user USB token.

Comment: Ok, store the certificate on USB token. But you have to perform PDF signing on client side and client will upload you signed PDF. You can validate if it is properly signed. But sharing client keys with server -- is a certainly bad idea, because client's private key leaks to web application and is no longer private.

Comment: @Crypt32 signing has been run on web application and we didn't storing any private keys on our server. We just want to pick the certificate from user usb token and perform the pdf signing on web application. We have done this activity in asp.net by using iTextSharp library for pdf signing but this works only on local system. We hosted this applicatiion on iis we are getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: @Crypt32 Can you tell me, It is possible to display dialog box to choose certificate from USB token for digital signing of PDF in ASP.Net C#.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: although, it is not a straight answer to your question, but may contain directions for you to get the right way depending on a business requirements. There are two major issues in your question. One of them I tried to discuss in comments, but may need to explain.

---

Let's try to analyze your initial post:

**Task:** let users to upload a PDF to web application and make it signed.

**Requirements:** the PDF must be signed by using a certificate stored on a client's USB token.

**Your proposed solution:** get client certificate (from the client) and perform signing on a server side.

---

Let's formalize terms and operations used in your scenario.

**Signing:** document signing is used to guarantee document integrity and ensure that the document was not tampered in any way after it was signed. Digital signaure provides information about the entity who performed signing. This adds non-repudiation feature. Once signed, signer cannot deny the signing fact and proves that the information in the document was correct at the signing time. Asymmetric signing requires private key. Associated public key can be used to verify and validate the signature.

**Private key:** is a part of a key pair which belongs to particular client. No one else should know private key.

**Security boundaries:** client (web browser or other web client) and web server run in different security boundaries and have different trust levels. They are under different administrative controls. As the result, web server has very limited access to client machine/data and vice versa: web client has very limited access to server machine/data.

---

Your proposed design assumes that client picks the document and upload it to a server. Then client picks a signing certificate (particularly, private key) and upload it to a server for signing operation.

**Issue #1:** once private key leaves client and is copied to your web application you are breaking security boundary. As the result, the key is no longer private, because web application possesses a knowledge of private key and it is stored (even if temporarily) in server memory. Or, in simple word, the key is leaked and compromised.

Client is no longer responsible for his key and operations made by the key. Client may deny anything that was made by using its private key. And deny signatures made by your web application.

**Issue #2:** your proposed design assumes that PDF is copied to a server as is. And only then it is signed. However, once the document (or its exact binary copy, to be more precise) touches the network, client is no longer responsible for document accuracy. Because the document may be transformed during transit or some code that touches the document between client and document signing code.

Once document leaves client machine, client is no longer responsible for document integrity, because the document is passed through various pieces of code that compose the document to a suitable for transmission format (encapsulation, for example). As the result, document sent by client and recieved by document signing code on a server side may not be the same. Document integrity is not guaranteed. Although, you can apply TLS to protect the document during transmit, there  still are places where the document can be anonymously tampered and no one will notice that.

Again, due to the fact that client cannot guarantee that web application received the same document he sent, client can deny the document you are trying to sign and deny the signature. Thus, making signature useless, because it proves nothing.

**Issue #3:** (not really an issue, but worth explanation) provided piece of code doesn't perform intended task (even though, it looks working in dev environment). Your goal is to invoke certificate selection dialog on client to select proper certificate.

During testing, you are running all the code locally. In debugger, the web application runs under currently logged user (which is interactive session) and is able to show the certificate selection dialog. However, you can't easily identify in which context (client or server) it is executed, because both, client and server run on the same machine and under the same security context. In fact, it is called under server context.

When you deploy the application to web server, you see the difference. Web application runs under some application pool context (user account) and this session is not interactive. As the result, `X509Certificate2UI` class cannot show the dialog, because no one will see it and no one can press buttons on it. This behavior is consistent regardless if the client and server run on the same or different machines, because IIS (or other web server) immediately separate concerns and security boundaries, while debugger does not. And client and server will definitely run under different security contexts. Even if you force to use the same context, IIS will make a secondary non-interactive user session to run the web application.

In order to show certificate selection dialog on client, you have to have a deep interaction with client, for example, via Silverlight (not sure if `X509Certificate2UI` is available in Silverlight) or some ActiveX control. You have to run some code on client side to accomplish that.

---

All stated above shows potential issues in your initial design, they simply break basic security rules. Technologies and tools are designed to follow these rules, not break them. By pursuing your initial design you will be forced to constantly fight with technologies to break them and making your application very insecure and vulnerable.

**Preferred solution:** we identified common risks in your design: key leak and document integrity between client and signing code on a server. To easily mitigate all this, you should do the only thing: perform document signing on client side. by doing this, signing private key will never leak from client and document integirty will be guaranteed over the course of signing and receipt by web application.

Now, we can talk about certificate properties. Your requirement is to use the certificate which is stored on a USB token. I don't know what kind of token you mean here. Is is a standard USB mass storage with PFX on it, or it is cryptographic device (smart card with USB interface, which is usually referred to USB token. For example, Aladdin (SafeNet) eToken devices).

If it is USB mass storage device, then it can't be a part of requirement, because generic USB drive does not offer anything helpful to identify the source of the certificate. Any certificate can be easily copied to USB drive and any certificate can be copied from USB drive.

If it is USB smart card, then there is a way to identify whether the certificate came from this device, or other source. Smart cards have one unique property: private key never leaves the card. All operations are performed on a card (this is the reason why they are slow comparing to certificates stored on PC).

This is usually accomplished by adding extra information to signing certificate during certificate issuance. For example, by adding `Certificate Policies` certificate extension. This will require that CA operator/manager ensures that certificates with specified certificate policies is deployed to smart cards only.

If these processes are established, you can use the code on server side that accepts signed PDF document and examines signing certificate contents. For example, you read certificate policies and expect to see particular entry there. If it is presented, then you can safely make assumptions that the document was signed by using the certificate stored on a smart card, because the key cannot be copied to anywhere from card device. If the certificate does not contain specific entry in certificate policies, then you can reject the documment acceptance and ask client to use proper certificate.