# locating a specific certificate from the Windows certificate store (C# - ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509

I have a web application that receives a signed token and should verify that signature with a certificate that is pre-installed at the end user's machine. I want to access the store and get the exact particular certificate that I want to use and so far I'm capable of reaching the store and count the certificates inside, but I can't find the particular certificate.

My strategy is to fill a `X509Certificate2Collection` with search results for the certificate by Subject Name as it is unique enough to pick the exact required certificate, then I pull the first element in the collection (hopefully the only) and use it, this is what I'm doing in the code below and so far I always get an exception that `certs` is empty and I can't convert nothing to string.

This works fine if I search with the serial number, but my certificate's serial number is 00 and I have 8 of these in my store!

How can I get a particular certificate from the store  and be able to use it programatically?

```
X509Store st0re = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            st0re.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            count = st0re.Certificates.Count;       //Count the certificates in the store
            X509Certificate2Collection certs = st0re.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                "C=US, S=WA, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Web Services",
                true);
            st0re.Close();

            Output = certs[0].ToString();       // = count.ToString()
```

Comment: `at the end user's machine` -- you mean, remote client? Hell, no! No way, sorry, because you are trying to do something wrong. Web application has no access to client resources. And shall not. There is an explained response to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707759/3997611

Comment: I'll clarify what I'm trying to do.. 
I have multiple web apps, connected to a third party SSO server, when the user navigates to a URL, he's redirected to that SSO server to log in, and redirected back with a signed cookie. I want to verify that cookie before I let him into my restricted pages. So I just want to load the certificate and use it to verify the token signature.

Comment: Look at the link above. It clearly explains why you can't and must not access client resources in web application. The required information must be either preconfigured in web application or supplied by client if the underlying protocol has such functionality. In your case, if cookie doesn't include the certificate, then you have to use local (web server) certificate store to obtain required certificate to validate the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considering the suggestions from @Crypt32, I moved my tokens to where the Application will be hosted, so this way I'm not looking on the end user's machine for a certificate, but instead it will be locally stored at the server hosting the application. To search for the token, I use the exact same code up there in the question with a very slight edit:

```
X509Store st0re = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        st0re.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        count = st0re.Certificates.Count;       //Count the certificates in the store
        X509Certificate2Collection certs = st0re.Certificates.Find(
            X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName,
            "C=US, S=WA, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Web Services",
            true);
        st0re.Close();

        Output = certs[0].ToString();       // = count.ToString()
```

All I did was to replace `X509FindType.FindBySubjectName` with `X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName`
In this case, all elements in the certificate subject have to be listed in that exact format.