# Sign a SOAP message with a client certificate located on the client's Smartcard via an asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, soap, ssl-certificate

I am able to retrieve the required certificate and sign the SOAP message within a desktop application running on my local machine just fine. (The process was basically: open my certificate store as the current user,select the correct certificate, enter pin, and the SOAP message was sent and responded to correctly).

**Example of desktop application certificate retrieval working:**

```
   X509Store store = new X509Store("MY",StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
```

Now we are moving this technology to a new intranet webapp and therefore we want our users to be able to use the same certificate to sign the same SOAP message to allow for data retrieval.

Reading several similar questions it looks as though opening my local certificate store is impossible in a WebApp as the client has no access to the local certificates located within the smart card. So with that I have shifted to forcing the website to require/negotiate SSL. From here I can go to the website and enter my pin and return the correct certificate via: `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);`

This however returns the error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel", the same error I got previously when I did not use the correct `SecurityProtocolType`option. I also noticed that when the certificate is accessed this way the Boolean `HasPrivateKey` is false versus being true when the certificate is accessed via the local store on the desktop application.

My questions are:

1) Is requiring the WebApp to negotiate Ssl and accessing the certificate via `Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate` (versus opening a certificate store in a particular fashion) the correct path to sign a SOAP message with a certificate?

2) I've saw several articles reference creating an ActiveX control to do this, if this is the correct way to accomplish the task where could I find some tutorials/resources on how to do this?

**Actual Problem Clarification:** Retrieving the personal certificate I need after forcing the web application to negotiate SSL via `X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);` has `HasPrivateKey`set to false and I'm pretty sure this is why I'm getting the error message "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" when trying to sign my SOAP message and retrieve a SAML token.

**Web Server Information:**
IIS 7.0, SSL required, windows authentication.

**Client PC information:**  The smart card software installed on the clients machine is ActivClient.

**Misc:** 
I am currently using SecurityProtocolType.Tls12.

Comment: This is perhaps a bit of a longshot, but are you running your developement environment on a virtual machine? VPN involved in any way..

Comment: @Örvar -- The code is currently published on a development web server that can be accessed with or without VPN.

Comment: Just a sidenote to my comment earlier. I had difficulties accessing certificatestore through code on my development environment hosted on a virtual machine. It had something todo with my wificard on the machine that hosted the virtual machine which resulted in if I remember correctly that the `HasPrivateKey` returned false. With ethernet it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: some time ago I wrote a tl;dr on a very similar subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis/46707759#46707759

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it's to big to be a comment, so I will write here nevertheless.

From my share of using smart cards, you're going to have a big issue, only a machine (or app hosted in the machine) can communicate with the smartcard, and a web application, it's hosted somewhere else and you will never-ever communicate directly with the smartcard, for security reasons (hence the creation of smartcards).

The only way to access the smartcard is to develop a local application that would safely communicate with your app, or, if you need to have a webapge, create an applet/activex control ... but activeX had their days over in IE, Edge no longer supports it...

> Microsoft dropped ActiveX support from the Windows Store edition of Internet Explorer 10 in Windows 8. In 2015, Microsoft Edge, the replacement for Internet Explorer, dropped ActiveX support, marking the end of the technology in Microsoft's web browser development.[14]

your only safe option is to create a java applet that runs on top of the Java SDK (client needs to install it)... that's what we use in banking.

Talking about banking ... how do you access your own banking account? You have probably need to enter a username/password/code into a java applet, no?

here in DanskeBank we login like that:

[image]

It's the only safe way to access hardware capabilities from a web page, as the http protocol is not that safe when using security algorithms.

You might also try to develop a browser plugin, but you will need to search for the smartcard support on access such hardware and I never tried such project.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your first paragraph. When you say "only a machine (or app hosted in the machine) can communicate with the smartcard" you mean machine as in the client's computer?

So a web application hosted on a web server doesn't count, correct? This concept is a little confusing to me because I can require Ssl via IIS and the web application will then prompt me for my pin via the ActivClient (the application that manages the smart card hardware) PIN popup window.

Comment: IIS does not tell the user to type his/her pin; IIS tells the user's browser that the website requires mutual authentication. It is the user's client-side browser that interacts with the smart card (via ActivClient) to get the certificate required to sign the HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

First answer. You will only need to have one certificate, placed on the server where the webapp is hosted. Your webapp will access the servers certificate store with similar code as you posted in the beginning of your question. Insted of calling the users certificate store, you will call the computers(servers) certificate store to get credentials needed to sign your soap message with. Check out how thumbprint is used to find the right certifcate. The thumbprint can be stored enqripted on the server hosting the webapp.

Second answer. You wrote that this was going to be an intranet solution, so I assume that the webapp is not publicly accessable. With tha said there is no need to develop any applet/activeX. Go for something simular to the first answer.

Comment: My problem is a little different because this is client verification. so all users will be using their personal certificate for signing a SOAP message to verify their access. So storing the certificates of all users would not be an option as it is a dynamic process. 

Now if I could access the clients personal certificates that have already been made available to windows (they are viewable under the certificates tab in IE ) **or** cross reference the httpContext.Request certificate (which has the same serial number and thumbprint I need) with Active Directory this would do the trick.