# How to get client certificate on my application mvc?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm developing a authentication system with a user certificates based on C# and MVC and I’m having some problems.

I use a SSL security with a CA certificate and I want to get back some certificates on a client side. When I run my application on the local side, I get the personal certificate, and  my authentication system works correctly.

However, when I  run the same application on the server side, I don't get back any personal certificate if it's installed in the navigator...

Here, you have the C# code that im developing.

```
private X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate()
{
    X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    try
    {
        userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection certificatesInStore = userCaStore.Certificates
                                                        .Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);
        X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;
        if (certificatesInStore.Count > 0)
        {

            clientCertificate = certificatesInStore[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        return clientCertificate;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        userCaStore.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course you don't get any certificate, because this code runs on a server, not on client.

Comment: And, why display a window to select one of personal certificates?

Comment: When running the code locally, both, client and server app run under the same security account on the same machine and it works. When server and client run on different machines, the code snippet you provided runs only on a server.

Comment: you can read more about this in a similar thread I engaged in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis/46707759#46707759

Comment: yes, I had read this documentation before, but how can take the subject of client certificate? I'm so confused

Comment: In controller or Views code you can access client certificate in the http context: `Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ClientCertificate`. This property is populated only when client elected to send the client certificate, otherwise it is empy or null.

Comment: To get the client certificate, is necessary that the server certificate was valid ? Although, in the both cases, local or server side, is empty or null

Comment: `To get the client certificate, is necessary that the server certificate was valid ?` -- yes. Client validates server certificate first. If validated and requested by server, client initiates client authentication by using client certificate. Client certificate request is configured in web server (IIS, for example).