# Why I don`t see a PIN prompt for SmartCard when I publish the webservice? C#, IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I want to sign an XML with X509 Certificate in C# Webservice.

1. Get the cert by thubmprint from x509Store

   ```
   private static bool GetCert(string thumbprint)
   {
       GlobalCert = new X509Certificate2();
       X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

       x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

       X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = x509Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

       x509Store.Close();

       if (certCollection.Count == 0) {
           return false;
       }

       foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in certCollection)
       {
           GlobalCert = cert;
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Signing the xml (user has to enter his PIN for the certificate)

   ```
   private static void SignXml(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
   {
       SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

       Reference reference = new Reference();
       reference.Uri = "#signedContent";
       signedXml.AddReference(reference);
       signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url;
       signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigC14NWithCommentsTransformUrl;

       KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
       keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(GlobalCert));
       signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
       if (GlobalCert.HasPrivateKey)
       {
           signedXml.SigningKey = GlobalCert.PrivateKey;
       }
       else
       {
           signedXml.SigningKey = GlobalCert.GetRSAPrivateKey();
       }
       signedXml.ComputeSignature();//Here the prompt for PIN pops up
       XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
       xmlDoc.FirstChild.FirstChild.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
   }
   ```
3. POST the xml

Great... It works but only in DEBUG (localhost:2626).

When I publish the webservice (localhost:8080) the prompt for pin request dont pop up.

My AppPool Identity is set to LocalService.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Check my tl;dr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis/46707759#46707759 scroll down to `Issue #3` section. It is your case.

Comment: Bonus extra info: If `HasPrivateKey` is false, both `PrivateKey` and `GetRSAPrivateKey()` return null.  (The method is preferred)