# Keeping Track of X509 Cert in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate

I currently have a DotNet Core app that's requiring a users x509 Certificate.  I currently can pull it and validate it with the following

In my Program.cs

```
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                    {
                        o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o => 
                            o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
                    });
                });
```

In my Startup.cs

```
            services.AddScoped<CertificateValidationService>();
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAuthentication(
                    CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCertificate(options =>
                {
                    options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                    options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            context.NoResult();
                            context.Response.Headers.Add("Token-Expired", "true");
                            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                        OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                        {
                            var validationService =
                                context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                                    .GetRequiredService<CertificateValidationService>();

                            if (validationService.ValidateCertificate(
                                context.ClientCertificate))
                            {

                                var claims = new[]
                                {
                                    new Claim(
                                        ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                                        context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                                        ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                        context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                                    new Claim(
                                        ClaimTypes.Name,
                                        context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                                        ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                        context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                                };

                                context.Properties.SetParameter("x509", context.ClientCertificate);
                                context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                                    new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                                context.Success();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                context.Fail($"Unrecognized client certificate: " +
                                             $"{context.ClientCertificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false)}");
                            }
                            return Task.CompletedTask;



                        }
                    };
                });

            services.AddControllers();
```

I also have my Implementation for verifying the cert and that works fine.    However, later in the application I want to do the following

```
        [Route("/signature")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string Signature()
        {
            
            using (var signer = new PdfDocumentSigner(@"C:\test\Document.pdf"))
            {
                ITsaClient tsaClient = new TsaClient(new Uri(@"https://freetsa.org/tsr"),
                    DevExpress.Office.DigitalSignatures.HashAlgorithmType.SHA256);

                string signatureName = signer.GetSignatureFieldNames(false)[0];


                // Create a provider that retrieves certificates from a store:
                //    public CertificateStoreProvider(X509Certificate2Collection collection);

                using (var certificateStoreProvider =
                    new CertificateStoreProvider(new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser), true))
                {
                    // Add the signature to the security store
                    // and specify the CrlClient and OcspClient objects
                    // used to check the certificates' revocation status:
                    
                    signer.AddToDss(signatureName, new CrlClient(), new OcspClient(), certificateStoreProvider);
                }
                signer.SaveDocument(@"C:\test\signedLTV.pdf", new[] { new PdfSignatureBuilder(new PdfTimeStamp(tsaClient)) });
            }

            return "The file was signed";
        }
```

Now obviously the problem is that this is the X509 Certificate on my Local Host.  BUT what I want to do is use the one that the user validated with which was passed along in the Program/Startup

Is there a way I can programmatically get that or pass that along safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. In order to use client certificate for subsequent cryptographic operations (like signing or decryption), you need a client's private key. However, client never sends its private key. Client's private key must never leave client machine. Your entire approach is non-working. Here is the relevant thread with a bit deeper explanation: [Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis)

What you can do is to move signing process to client side (execute in browser), but this approach has its own issues, like you will have to download entire PDF to client browser, sign somehow and then upload back to server.