# Sign a file with HttpClientCertificate certificate

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I`m working on sign manager involving web-based Smart Card authentication. Up to now I successfully auth with Smrt Card and extract the certificate.

```
[RequireHttps]
public class AuthController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Auth(string AuthToken = "")
    {
       
        

        if (Request.ClientCertificate.IsPresent && Request.ClientCertificate.IsValid)
        {
             x509CertificateValidator.Validate(new X509Certificate2(Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate));
            var parsedData = x509CertificateManager.GetCertificateData(Request.ClientCertificate);              
            parseResult.Add(parsedData);
        }
     
        return View(parseResult);
    }
```

Validate:

```
public void Validate(X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        var myChainPolicy = new X509ChainPolicy
        {
            RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online,
            RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain,
            VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag,
            UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10),
            VerificationTime = DateTime.Now
        };

        var chain = new X509Chain(true) { ChainPolicy = myChainPolicy };

        try
        {   
            if (!chain.Build(cert))
                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Validation failed while building the chain");
            if (CRLVerification.IsCertificateInCrl(cert))
                throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("The certificate is revoked byCRL"); 
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenValidationException("Validation failed while building the chain , " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Extract certificate data:

```
  public ParseResult GetCertificateData(HttpClientCertificate clientCretificate)
    {       
        X509Certificate2 x509Cert2 = new X509Certificate2(clientCretificate.Certificate);
        CertificateParser cp = new CertificateParser(x509Cert2);
        ParseResult pr = new ParseResult();
        pr = cp.Parse();

        return pr;
    }
```

And the problem is when I would like to sign some file(word,pdf,xml and so on)
So HttpClientCertificate neither contains the private key associated with the certificate nor any dynamic data signed by the private key in order to authenticate the TLS session.

It`s posible to cenerate or extract the privite key to sign a file base on current certificate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis)

Comment: The problem is that the whole your idea is wrong. I've explained what and why it is wrong in the following thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707759/3997611. Basically, you don't own this certificate, so you cannot access its private key. If you need to sign something with client certificate, do this on client side.