# Signing XML in .Net with Smart Card

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate2, signedxml

My client have a smart card in his computer and when he access my application through browser I can access the `X509Certificate2` class of the connected smart card. The problem is that I need to sign a XML with his information and the privatekey, RSA private key and DSA private key is null in the X509 class. I have a WPF program that show the privatekey but when I need to access in browser through my .Net Core app don't work.

I'm using IIS by the way.

I'm getting the information of his card on `Program.cs` in the service:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate(options => {
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents {
            OnCertificateValidated = context => {
                context.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate = context.ClientCertificate; // <- that line
            };
        });
```

The context.ClientCertificate don't has a privatekey and when I call the `ComputeSignature` method in `SignedXml` class I got the error `CryptographicException "Signing key is not loaded"`.

How I get the privatekey of the smartcard or how I proceed to get the `SignedXml.ComputeSignature` working?

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
It helped me to see that I'm thinking wrong about certificates and the private key. If I understood it, I think that I need to search how to sign the XML on the client side without sending the private key through network. I will search more about this and if I need I will open other question. For now, your answer is enough to put me in the right way. Thanks!