# Unable to access cert store of current user in ASP.NET Core application when deployed to IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis, x509certificate

I am trying to access cert store of current user in my ASP.NET Core application via
x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)

The code works fine locally but when deployed on IIS, StoreLocation.CurrentUser always returns IIS default user. Tried below things:

1. Changed IIS impersonation setting to enabled
2. Added web.config manually with identity impersonation true.

Can anybody help me with the issue ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core does not implement impersonation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation

Comment: I checked the Microsoft documentation about the same .... Wondering what is the alternate approach , if not IIS then any other way to host the code to access the cert store on windows server

Comment: `I am trying to access cert store of current user in my ASP.NET Core application` it's not clear which user store you need to access? Currently logged user? Why you would want this?

Comment: @Crypt32 I want to access cert store of current user as i using smart card for some cryptographic operations in my application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis)

Comment: @vranda it is not possible and you want to do things wrong. See this response on a same subject: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707759/3997611

Comment: @Crypt32, I read the thread, the problem is slightly different there as the solution works perfectly when i locally start the server, and isn't it the same use case as performing document signing and authentication via smart cards in a service call. On IIS, the application returns the current user as IISDefaultAppUser and not the logged in windows user when we use StoreLocation.CurrentUser.

Comment: @Crypt32 I guess we are referring to two different cases. Here cert stays in client machine (in the smart card) and not server and when this service runs on each individual machine as local service which uses Smart Card for Cryptography operations. So, the document signing example is not valid

Comment: This may be a permission issue, you can try this method to go to the access cert store of current users, `X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)`, the application pool uses the following settings: `Identity: LocalSystem; Load User Profile: True`.

Comment: Tried this but it also returns the current user as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. I am deploying on DefaultAppPool as of now.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.