# Failure to find private key in X509 Certificate on eToken

Tags: certificate, x509

I have been issued a certificate that is stored on a SafeNet eToken.  The public key is saved in a database on each user account.  I use the code below to find a certificate on an eToken using the thumbprint.  I then use the private key to generate a digital signature.  It works perfectly when I run my code on my PC using IISExpress.  However, when I publish the application to a server on IIS the application fails to find the certificate and therefore is unable to get the private key to sign.

I am new to cryptography and this could be the reason I am facing this issue.  I am seeking your help:

Below is my code that works on IISExpress

```
    public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore(string thumbprint)
    {


        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My);
        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;

            X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

            if (currentCerts.Count > 0)
            {
                X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, true);
                if (signingCert.Count > 0)

                    return signingCert[0];
            }

            return null;

        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
    }
```

Our security team who issue me the certificate on the eToken told me to try installing the SafeNet drivers on the server which I did but has not resolved the issue.  I have also tried that goes through all possible store locations and store names searching for the certificate but still not able to find the certificate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis)

Comment: Thanks Crypt32. The link gives me some pointers that I need to explore first.  The problem is the same.