How to use client certificate private key in C# Web APIs?
I am trying to use client certificate in my C# web APIs in order to sign generated PDF document(s). I managed to allow client certificate in Startup.cs using the following code:
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o => 
        {
            o.ClientCertificateMode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
            o.AllowAnyClientCertificate();
            o.ClientCertificateValidation = (cert, chain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };
            o.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
        }
    );
});

Then, in controller endpoint method, I am able to access client certificate via:
var certificate = await this.HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();

where certificate variable is of type X509Certificate2. However, certificate passed to API has no private key - HasPrivateKey property is false and PrivateKey property is null.
I have to mention that certificate which I use as a test case has corresponding private key (ie. when accessed via Manage user certificates on my Windows 11 PC).

This question is similar to: Open X509 Certificates Selection Using USB Token in C# Hosted on IIS. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Fundamentally, your problem is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46686462/open-x509-certificates-selection-using-usb-token-in-c-sharp-hosted-on-iis. Basically, it doesn't work the way you want to. Server never has access to client's private keys. Either, do document signing on client side, or use server's own certificate to sign documents.

@Crypt32 thank you for your helpful comment. I have read the proposed solution, but to me it seems pretty time consuming to for my users to sign hundreds of documents which are 99% equal, the only difference is recipient details (name, address, ...)

You have to deal with this technical limitation due to a security restriction. No browser will send clients private keys to server, browsers have no access to keys. And what if key is stored on a chip (smart card, HSM, TPM, other key vault type) when key is not exportable? Your question in its current state doesn't have other answers.
